# cfchart HTML format not available

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfchart

I'm trying to use cfchart with html format:

```
<cfchart format="html" type="bar" chartHeight="600" chartWidth="1100" title="Sales Chart"
   font="Arial" fontBold="true" fontSize="13"
>
    <cfchartseries type="line" seriesColor="##3232FF">
        <cfloop query="getData">
            <cfchartdata item="#Date#" value=#sales#>
        </cfloop>
    </cfchartseries>
</cfchart>
```

However, it is returning the error:

```
Client Side Charting is not available in this edition of ColdFusion server.
```

I'm using CF10 and I control the server. How can I enable the cfchart format HTML? BTW, if I change the format to png, it works.

Comment: Standard or Enterprise? HTML5 charts required Enterprise version back in CF10. (IIRC, that's no longer the case in later versions)

Comment: Standard and CF10

Comment: [According to this](https://web.archive.org/web/20121025230959/http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/cf10/coldfusion-comparison.pdf) HTML5 charts weren't available in Standard. Only with the Enterprise version. CF10 is now EOL'd.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.